# What is the oldest continuously circulating story that survived until 1890’s?

Tags: ancient-history, political-history, cultural-history, social-history, religious-history

What is the oldest continuously circulating story (specifically prior 13th century BCE) that survived until 1890’s? (eg myths/histories etc)

I am specifically looking for a myth/story/history that SURVIVED through the ages (meaning; that humans CONTINUOUSLY knew this myth/story/history) – as opposed to a myth/story/history that was REDISCOVERED (eg via archaeology).
It doesn’t matter to me HOW it survived – whether by written account, oral tradition, a combination or any other method.

The reason why I care about this;

> A person I know claimed to me that the [Black Israelites believed the story their preacher told them (that they were the real Jews who were at Mount Sinai)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hebrew_Israelites) at a time in history when there was ZERO surviving information from 1313 BCE.

I have already ruled out:

- The Legend of King Sargon of Akkad, Mesopotamian creation mythology, Laws of Hammurabi, Egyptian Story of Sinuhe, Hittite history/mythology. All of those were REDISCOVERED in the last few hundred years.
- Greek and Roman Mythology, and Buddhist Oral traditions. They are not old enough to be relevant to this.

I am unsure about anything written in hieroglyphics, because on the one hand it was unintelligible for most of history (until the translation of the Rosetta stone), but on the other hand there were monuments etc (with hieroglyphics) that DID survive and WERE known of by humans.

Comment: The myth of Osiris is mentioned in pyramid texts from the 24th century BCE and has been continuously known via the accounts in Plutarch and other writers.

Comment: Not an expert, but the most likely answer for eldest might be Chinese mythology--the quasi-historical Xia dynasty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xia_dynasty predates the period you are interested in.

Comment: You might consider rephrasing this to ask what the **oldest** continuously circulating story is (or words to that effect). I think we're better at that kind of question than at "yes or no" questions, and it would get you what you want, if I'm reading this correctly.

Comment: Stories & myths aren't discrete - they get continuously appropriated, adapted, and adopted by other cultures that are proximate in time and space.  Who first owns the flood myth? Is there a single flood myth through successive cultures or do they all invent one to deal with their reality? What's the boundary between a myth and a trope?  This is a very interesting question, but before I'd start research I'd have to do some solid thinking about definitions.  Joseph Campbell (et. al.) come to mind.

Comment: @MCW I think that the only point of yours that is relevant to my question is "adapted". For the purpose of my question, if the story has been adapted (ie CHANGED), then I would consider its date of origin to be the date of adaption.

Comment: Why 13th c BCE? Why 1890s?

Comment: And what constitutes a story?  Because Cupid and Psyche is recognizably a form of the fairy tale type that also has East of the Sun, West of the Sun.  Would you deem them one story or two?  Because that would certainly affect it.

Comment: @shoover 13th c BCE because that's when the Revelation at Sinai happened, and 1890's because that's when the Black Israelite group started.

Comment: The judeo-christian mythology of creation and of the chosen people.

Answer (score 2):

### Menes - c.3000 BCE

Although much garbled by a millennia-long game of "telephone" from unreliable and biased historians, many of the kings of ancient Egypt have been recorded continously up to the present.

> Further, the Egyptians (said they) first used the appellations of twelve gods​ (which the Greeks afterwards borrowed from them); and it was they who first assigned to the several gods their altars and images and temples, and first carved figures on stone. They showed me most of this by plain proof. The first human king of Egypt, he said, was **Min**.

-[Herodotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herodotus), *Histories*

> In succession to the Spirits of the Dead and the Demigods, the Egyptians reckon the First Dynasty to consist of eight kings. Among these was **Mênês**, whose rule in Egypt was illustrious...

-[Syncellus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Syncellus), in a fragment of Eusebius's *Chronicon* which excerpted [Manetho](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Manetho/home.html)'s *[Aegyptiaca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manetho#Aegyptiaca)*. ([LacusCurtius](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Manetho/History_of_Egypt/1*.html)), Bill Thayer 's website at the University of Chicago

The Hellenistic Egyptian priest Manetho compiled a list of kings outlining the dynasty structure still used today, but with gaps filled in by modern discoveries.

Manetho's *Aegyptiaca* only survives in epitomes and excerpts in other works, but of particular note is the *[Chronicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicon_(Eusebius)_)* by [Eusebius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eusebius), which itself only exists in fragments. Syncellus's excerpt of Eusebius was later  excerpted in Latin translation by [Anastasius the Librarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anastasius_Bibliothecarius).

Even with all of this slicing and dicing, however, we do know that Manetho called the first king of the First Dynasty "Menes" (called "Min" by Herodotus), Most Egyptologists identify Menes with the historicaly-attested king [Narmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narmer), as both names appear to be associated with a king who united Upper and Lower Egypt in the late 4th (or early 3rd) millennium BCE. The runner-up is Narmer's successor [Hor-Aha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hor-Aha).

Menes's death is briefly described as "carried away by a hippopotamus" although there's no knowing how old that detail really is.

Sumerian works such as the *Epic of Gilgamesh* and the Sumerian King List were lost and only rediscovered in the 19th Century, so Menes is likely the oldest.

Comment: Great YouTube video about Menes: https://youtu.be/FbCIhb40d8g